# Estimating incidence on data with limited observation

Tags: conditional-probability, observational-study

I have a data of many individuals and wish to know whether a certain event occurred during a specific time frame with each one. The problem is that each individual was observed only a certain portion of this time frame.

Is there a way to extrapolate my observations to consider the possibility of the event occurring during the time I wasn't observing?

Case in point: during the course of a month I wish to know, from a group of people, who visited a specific place, but while for some of them I have data for all 31 days in question, for others I have 20, 10, or even only one day's worth of information. I my goal is to estimate the proportion of people that visited the place at least once over all people considered.

What I considered as an estimator is:

$$
\frac{\sum{visited(i)}}{\sum{visited(i)+{t^i_{obs}}/{t_{tot}}}(1-visited(i))}
$$

where:
$visited$ is 1 if $i$ visited the place during observed time and 0 if they haven't 
$t^i_{obs}$ is the time I have observed the person $i$ 
$t_{tot}$ is the total time considered

This estimator allows me to consider that if I know someone visited, it considers it fully, but if the person did not visit during the observed time, it considers that longer observed times represent a higher probability of the person not having visited. My problem with it is that it seems to favor having visited too much.

Any ideas for a better estimator? Or maybe whether my estimator is decent or not?

Comment: If all you have is time as a covariate, it is incredibly unlikely you would be able to extrapolate effectively.  I mean, can you tell me if I went to Starbucks this month if all I tell you is that I didn't go to Starbucks for 20 days out of the month?